# Unable to choose desired layer when georeferencing in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, georeferencing

I am georeferencing some images in ArcMap 10.3.1.

When I want to add the specific layer I'm going to georeference, I cannot choose this from the drop-down menu.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: what is the source of your images?  Do you have access to modify them?

Comment: The source of the images is .tif. And I just tried opening the image in a blank map and then it did work!

Answer (score 2):

Try opening a new blank map, adding just that image, and seeing if it appears in the Georeferencing toolbar.

If you are working with an existing map either you or ArcMap may have lost track of its available layers.

Starting with a clean slate map is the way I advocate to try and take out multiple factors that could be coming into play at one hit.

Comment: You were exactly right - doing so helped! Sometimes ArcMap can be weird I think. Very nice input you gave me there.

Comment: I have the same issue: an image is not available to georeference in the drop-down menu.  If I open a new blank map, the image is available.  But that doesn't "solve" my problem because I need the information from my existing map to proceed with georeferencing. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @user3386170 you could try adding that other information into your new map too.

Comment: That is not an option given the number of layers in my map (I could also start all over in QGIS but I'm looking for a solution for my map without starting over). Would it be possible to get more information about keeping "track of its available layers"?  Why/how does ArcGIS decide which layers I want to edit and which layers I do not want to edit?

Comment: You've not described a procedure by how your map became unable to offer you this TIF so I cannot speculate on what led you to ask this question, but if I had a lot of layers in one MXD and wanted them in another I would highlight them, right-click and Copy, then in the second map right-click on the data frame and Paste Layer(s).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with some .tif images not appearing in the Georeferencing toolbar, while other .tif's from the same project appear. I noticed the hint that appears when holding the mouse cursor over the Georeferencing toolbar: "`...Only raster layers that are not projected on the fly can be georeferenced`".

In my case the raster was projected on the fly while those that appeared in the georeferencing toolbar were not. The solution was to project the problematic raster (using Project Raster from Data Management) into the coordinate system of the data frame. Therefore, the image was visible in the Georeferencing toolbar.